# Jgit add folder structure and files underneath

Tags: git, jgit

I am creating a folder structure files on the fly using java code. After creation of folder and files I want to add both folder structure and files underneath using JGIT.
I am trying to use below code

```
  git.add().addFilepattern(folder.getName()).call(); 
  git.add().addFilepattern(file.getName()).call();
```

but it adds only files to git repo .
Is there any different way to add folders to git using JGIT

Comment: [Did you take a look at JGit's User Guide? There's a reference about that exact code snippet on it.](https://wiki.eclipse.org/JGit/User_Guide)

Comment: Yes, I have followed section:AddCommand (git-add) in doc but still empty folder structure is not getting added

Answer (score 1):

This is not caused by JGit, but a limitation in Git itself. It does by default not store folders, only files.

So you cannot add an empty folder to Git.

As workaround you can add a dummy-file (a commonly used name is `.gitkeep`) or add a `.gitignore` file.

.gitignore:

```
Another way to make a directory stay (almost) empty (in the repository) is to create a .gitignore file inside that directory that contains these four lines:

# Ignore everything in this directory
*
# Except this file
!.gitignore
```

.gitkeep:

```
touch <dir>/.gitkeep
```

See the following links with detailed description of these workarounds:

- [How can I add a blank directory to a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115983/how-can-i-add-a-blank-directory-to-a-git-repository)
- https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/gitkeep-push-empty-folders-git-commit